# centos command at

Tags: linux, centos, at

добавляю так at -f myscript.sh 11:00
получил номер процесса, например 7

atq выдало

```
7 2015-08-21 11:00 a some_user
```

в myscript.sh следующее

```
php makefile.php
```

в makefile.php

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('log.log', 'w');
fwrite($fp, date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
fclose($fp);
?>
```

но файла нигде нет

at -c 7
ничего не выводит

если выполнить

```
sh myscript.sh
```

то файл нормально создается...

что я делаю не так?

почему через at не хочет отрабатывать?
как время прошло, есть пометка, что выполнено
atq после 11 утра выдало

```
7 2015-08-21 11:00 ! some_user
```

Comment: а вы выполняете команду `at ...` в том каталоге, где находится `makefile.php`?

Comment: да, находясь в каталоге с makefile.php и myscript.sh

Comment: пользователь, от имени которого вы всё это делаете, упоминается в [файлах `/etc/at.allow` и `/etc/at.deny`](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-autotasks-at-batch.html#s2-autotasks-at-batch-service)?

Comment: доступа к этим файлам нет, в папке /etc есть только файл at.deny, но его содержимое мне не известно.
каким должно быть содержимое этих файлов, чтобы команды работали?

Comment: по приведённой ссылке, мне кажется, всё написано. пользователя не должно быть в файле `/etc/at.deny`.

Comment: спасибо, узнаю что в файле.

Comment: *at -c 7 ничего не выводит* — вы выполняли эту команду **до** 11:00 или **после**? информация о задании удаляется после его выполнения.

Comment: для проверки, работает ли что-то, выполните, пожалуйста, вот этот набор комманд (целиком вставив их в командную строку) и весь вывод после завершения (оно займёт две минуты) приложите к вопросу: `echo touch /tmp/some.file | at 'now+1min'; atq; sleep 120; ls -l /tmp/some.file`. отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. если в файле `/etc/at.deny` перечислен и пользователь, от имени которого вы пытаетесь сделать *at*-задание, а файла `/etc/at.allow` не существует, то при попытке создать задание вы получите сообщение вида:

   > You do not have permission to use at.
2. если файл `/etc/at.allow` существует, то пользователь должен быть там перечислен (одна строка — одно имя). иначе получите то же сообщение.
3. чтобы проверить работоспособность `at`, можно создать простое задание типа:

   ```
   $ echo touch /tmp/some.file | at 'now+1min'
   job 459 at Fri Aug 21 17:47:00 2015
   ```

   если всё в порядке, в указанный момент времени выполнится команда `touch /tmp/some.file`. если такой файл появился — всё в порядке и вам надо разбираться с вашим способом вызова задания.